# How can I protect the specific memory by using mprotect?

Tags: c, memory, memory-address, mprotect

I want to protect a specific memory area by using mprotect.

So I wrote code to give a virtual address to protect but mprotect is not working.

Is there any problem in my code?

here is my code.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    size_t vaddr = strtoull(argv[1], NULL, 0); //./a.out 0xffff880446ced000

    printf("addr : %p\n", vaddr);

    if(mprotect(vaddr, 0x1000, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE)==-1) {
        printf("mprotect error\n");
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first argument to `mprotect()` should be `void *`, not `size_t`.

Comment: Are you sure the address is allocated to the process? How does the caller know what address to pass as an argument?

Comment: Is it getting an error? You should use `perror()` to report the reason for the error.

Comment: Suggest `size_t vaddr` --> `unsigned long long vaddr`.   `printf("addr : %p\n", vaddr);` --> `printf("addr : %p\n", (void*) vaddr);`

Comment: Thanks all. I tried to perror(), but it returns msg : Cannot allocate memory.

Comment: @karoha I will come back and look at this; this was a very good question!